# Graphics lags after suspend. Ubuntu 16.04 NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

After suspend ubuntu 16.04 this weird stuff on borders of every window.
I have tried four of this drivers but it not helps.
Drivers:[image]
[image]

Comment: With the newest system update and 381.09 from repository, the problem has not occured yet. No glitches and freezing so far after returning from suspend. I have 1060GTX.
EDIT: probably false alarm. After second returning from suspend and couple of minutes working, screen glitches occured again. Improvement is, that glitches are no longer visible immediately after returning from suspend, but it will finally occure for sure :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same Issue and this didn't solve it but helped to get rid of the weird borders after suspending. Type in a terminal window:

unity --replace

It restarts unity without the weird borders and you don't loose any windows or applications that are currently open.

I found this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/466385/ubuntu-14-04-window-problem-after-waking-up-from-suspend

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this morning after updating to kernel 4.8.0-45 (HWE) on my 16.04 machine w/ an nVidia 650ti. I tried booting with the previous kernel (4.8.0-41), but I had the same issue. I tried the Noveau drivers, but for some reason they would not recognize either monitor properly (stuck at 1024x768 res on single monitor), so that was unusable. I then tried using switching from the 375.39 proprietary drivers to the 340.102 drivers and that worked (on the latest HWE kernel 4.8.0-45). I see that 340.102 is not available to you, but try one of the other driver versions to see if the problem goes away.